# Cocoa pods lint source path error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

while i create my cocoa pod, have some problem.
in Xcode creating new framework project with some classes. My project struct is

-podspec

-Classes

--source classes {.h, .m}

-Project

--projectName folder

--projectName.xcodeproj

Yes. and if pod spec lint i see 1 error

> ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match
>   any file.

but in pod spec s.source_files  = "Classes", "Classes/**/*.{h,m}" or s.source_files  = "Classes/***/.{h,m}" 
Please, help me.

Comment: I don't use Cocoapods but that spec looks like it needs `Classes` and `podspec` in the same directory.  As you have explained, you haven't got that.  I don't see the point of the `Project` directory, so I would dump it and move everything into the top-level, like every other project out there.

Comment: Yes, i mistake this struct. pod spec, project and classes in one level directory. Edit post